# How do i install a unicode chart?

Tags: windows, unicode

I'm having some display problems with unicode character which requires a font to be installed on my OS. does anyone know where can i get a specific chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to have unicode characters displaying correctly:

Installing office (or it's demo) installs unicode versions of certain system fonts, so you could install the trial version of office to get the fonts you need. You can then uninstall office and it will leave the unicode versions of the fonts behind.

If you're still having problems after that, (and again making assumptions that you're having troubles viewing them on the web), you will need to make sure that your browser is set to display utf-8, and not something more language specific. How to change it differs somewhat per browser (for example in Firefox it's in preferences > content and then advanced font options)